# CakePHP redirect with form parameter

Tags: cakephp-3.0

In CakePHP 3.1 I am redirecting to login page after a database update and I want to pass back the email so that form input is already populated.

I can do it the standard way with using the controller and action in the redirect.

Instead I am using just a url string

`return $this->redirect('/login',['?' => ['email' => $email]]);`

This gives me the error Unknown status code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirect method expects a status code as the second parameter. You will need to provide and array-based URL as the first parameter or append the query var to the current string.

`return $this->redirect('/login?email=' . $email);`

`return $this->redirect([
    'controller' => 'Users',
    'action' => 'login',
    '?' => [
        'email' => $email
    ]
]);`

Comment: thanks, I don't want the url to be base/controller/action so I will go with your first suggestion

Comment: one last issue, sorry. passing as `?` POST does not populate the email input form. How could I pass as GET

Comment: All the query vars are available in the request object so you could set the value of the email input with that.

<input type="email" value="<?= $this->request->query['email'] ?>">

Comment: I am trying t keep my Templates as dry as possible, I see the plugin CakeAdmin does this `return $this->redirect($this->Auth->config('loginAction') + ['email' => $email]);`

Comment: By the looks of things they do it like this https://github.com/cakemanager/cakephp-cakeadmin/blob/master/src/Controller/Admin/UsersController.php#L73

Comment: No problem, I didn't realise forms automatically populated like that with POST data!